# how to set onclick listener recyclerview and start new activity on each click

Tags: android

I am working with `recyclerview` and I am not able to start new activity
on each click. How to start new activity recyclerview?

Following is my code:

Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recycler_view;
    private Custom_Adapter custom_adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recycler_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        custom_adapter = new Custom_Adapter(dataList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recycler_view.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recycler_view.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recycler_view.setAdapter(custom_adapter);

        prepareMovieData();
    }

    private void prepareMovieData() {

        Data data = new Data("Preamble");

        dataList.add(data);

        data = new Data("Parts");
        dataList.add(data);

        data = new Data("Schedules");
        dataList.add(data);

        data = new Data("Amendments");
        dataList.add(data);

        data = new Data("Quiz");
        dataList.add(data);

        custom_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class Custom_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Custom_Adapter.MyViewHolder>  {

    private List<Data> dataList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener  {

        public View view;

        public TextView title;

        public MyViewHolder(final View itemView)  {
            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    }

    public Custom_Adapter(List<Data> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int position) {

        final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.data_list_row,parent,false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        Data data = dataList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(data.getTitle());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }
}
```

Data.java:

```
public class Data {

    String title;

    public Data(){}

    public Data(String title){
        this.title=title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String name) {
        this.title = name;
    }
}
```

I want to start new activity on each click. What should I do to start new? Can I use switch case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is some code with an example showing how to use switch for this. But, to use it vertabim you'll need a proper callback pattern - ie. create the onClickListener as an anonymous class and pass it into the adapters constructor. Then have the adapter keep a reference and pass it to the VH onBind

```
//in Adapter, Viewholder
private View.OnClickListener mCallback;

public Custom_Adapter(List<Data> dataList, View.OnClickListener callback) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
    mCallback = callback;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(mCallback);
    holder.itemView.setTag(position);
    ...
}

//in Activity

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    custom_adapter = new Custom_Adapter(dataList, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Class<? extends Activity> target;
            switch( (int) view.getTag() ) {
                case 0:
                    target = PreambleActivity.class;
                    break;
                ...
            }

            if (target != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, target);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ( Variable target may not initialized ) . this is happen when i write this
  if (target != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, target);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

Comment: So just initialise it to null when you create it

Answer (score 0):

You should start new activity inside onClick method of Viewholder like below

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener  {

public View view;

public TextView title;

public MyViewHolder(final View itemView)  {
    super(itemView);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

// To get context. You can pass it to the adapter from activity when  
// creating the instance of adapter or you can get it from Viewgroup 
// inside onCreateViewHolder using parent.getContext().  

startActivity(new Intent(context, NewActivity.class));

}
}
```

Comment: That would hard code the same activity to every item, also startActivity isn't available from there

Comment: Pass reference of activity to adapter, as long as you don't do something silly like save the reference in a static variable in adapter, it won't cause a leak. And yes, it will attach a new click listener to every ViewHolder, and that is how everyone does it. Or just make a click listener in scope of adapter and use that